# In prepared statement is setString() the only useful method to prevent SQL injection?

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement, sql-injection

What's the need to use:

```
    pstatement.setInt();  
    pstatements.setFloat(); 
    etc.
```

and all these methods other than **setString()** which is the only method useful to prevent SQL injection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite simple, most databases prepare the statement separately from sending the parameters and executing the statement. It is this separation of statement and parameters that actually provide the protection against SQL injection (in contrast to manually escaping and concatenating strings in a query). The format these parameters are sent in is usually specific for the datatype in the database.

Assuming you use the equivalent types in both the database and in Java (eg `BIGINT` <> `long`, `VARCHAR` <> `String`, `TIMESTAMP` <> `java.sql.Timestamp`) then using the type specific setters will lead to less conversions. Say `int` -> 4 byte big-endian encoding instead of `String` -> `int` -> 4 byte big-endian encoding.

And furthermore it leads to less clutter in your code, because you don't need to convert to `String` first from your Java specific datatype.

Now JDBC does support `setString` for a lot of database types (see appendix B of JDBC 4.2 for the conversions), so nothing stops you from only using `setString`. But from the point of view for ease of use I don't know why you'd want to do that; the type specific methods are a lot easier to use.

Comment: yes, what I don't understand is that setInt(int ind,int val) accepts an int as the value to be inserted, how can an int value generate a sql injection attack ? so why don't use the value directly in the query without using a wildcard for it ?

Comment: @user986437 protection against SQL injection is a side effect of using parameters: it isn't the primary reason to use parameters. You can prepare a statement once and then reuse it with different sets of parameters, which is a lot more efficient than creating unique statements with different values.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to validate the input before sending it to the database to be rejected, you can use the appropriate 'set' statement, and put try/catch blocks around them. That way you can provide feedback to the user before having to send a command to the database.

Comment: Validating that the input from the user is correct (e.g. they've entered a number when you're expecting one) should be an entirely separate method called before you ever got around to connecting to a database and creating a prepared statement.

Comment: Yes, ideally, but that doesnt change the fact that these methods exist for that reason. The reason `setInt()` exists is to validate that you are in fact working with an int value, rather than a float or a string or whatever.

Comment: It "validates" that when you're writing the code, though, since trying to pass a String to a method that takes an int parameter results in a compile time error, not a runtime one. I don't think that's the (only) reason those methods exist at all.